# «Chosen» plugin jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have two question concerning the [chosen plugin](https://github.com/julesjanssen/chosen/):

1. How I can see result array with right turn (['firstSelected', 'secondSelected', etc.])? At this moment plugin return all values sorting by index.
2. How I can listen mouse events on the elements of chosen list? I want to create drag and drop list. All the events are prevent by plugin.

Comment: While I don't quite understand what you're asking, I'm pretty sure Select2 will help: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: oh, sorry I forgot this question. yes I choose the same plugin, cause it's very functionality and better than chosen.